# How to know that a tree node is partially visible?

Tags: c#, winforms, visible, treenode

"TreeNode.IsVisible" is available but I can't tell from it whether it's visible or partially visible - "true if the tree node is visible or partially visible".

e.g. How can I tell if the following "Temporary ASP.NET" tree node is partially visible?

Also, how the text hovers directly over the node is called? Is it a tooltip in the end? Can it be controled on visibility?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TreeNode.Bounds.Right property and compare against TreeView.ClientRectangle.Right

Comment: Also, do you know how the text hovers directly over the node is called? Is it a tooltip in the end? Can it be controled on visibility?